# Check if element value starts with 'http', if true change class of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check a series of elements with the same class to see if their value starts with 'http' if this is true those elements should have a new class added.

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    if ($('span.value').text().indexOf('http') == 0 ) 
    {
        $('span.value').addClass('url'); 
    } else {
        $('span.value').addClass('notURL');
    }
});
```

This [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rkws8bs6/19/) is what I've got so far, but It's adding the new class to all elements even the ones that don't start with 'http'.

I'm not sure what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over each span individually:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('span.value').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf('http') == 0) {
            $(this).addClass('url');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('notURL');
        }
    })
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rkws8bs6/22/)**

Comment: Thanks, knew I was missing something really simple.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking only span you have to use `.each` function to check all span one by one:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
   $('span.value').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('http') == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('url');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('notURL');
    }
})
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rkws8bs6/23/)

Your code is checking of one(first of DOM) `span` element and applying css to all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/#addClass-function) with a function

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('span.value').addClass(function(){
        return $(this).text().indexOf('http') == 0 ? 'url' : 'notURL';
    });        
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4fbrvkdL/)

You need to iterate over each element to check the text value.  By using addClass with function `this` will refer to the current element in the set.

```
.addClass( function )
function
Type: Function( Integer index, String currentClassName ) => String
A function returning one or more space-separated class names to be added to
the existing class name(s). Receives the index position of the element in the 
set and the existing class name(s) as arguments. Within the function, this 
refers to the current element in the set.
```

Answer (score 0):

Manwal answer is good, but if you want to specificaly check if value or string starts with "http" I recommend using javascript [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) like this:

```
var name = "http://";
var containsHTTP = name.substring(0,4) == 'http' ? 'yess' : 'no';
alert(containsHTTP);

// How to use it in your code    
$('#btn').click(function () {
    if ($('span.value').text().substring(0,4) == 'http' ) 
    {
        $('span.value').addClass('url'); 
    } else {
        $('span.value').addClass('notURL');
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/86375hpz/)

Answer (score 0):

`$("span.value").text()` will return a string containing the text of every span with class value, in your example: `http://google.co.ukhttp://www.barratthomes.co.uk:80/globalassets/property-c…trumpington-meadows_new.jpg?preset=Original&v=20150625112515873CheeseCream`

And this will change the class of every span.value: `$('span.value').addClass('url');`

What you need to do is to iterate over each span individually, something like this:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('span.value').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf('http') == 0) {
            $(this).addClass('url');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('notURL');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget `https` and `://`.

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('span.value').each(function()
    {
        var match = /^https?:\/\//.test($(this).text());
        $(this).addClass(match ? 'url' : 'notURL');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your problem is that you are always adding the two classes to all your elements you should use `$(this)` instead of `$('span.value')`

You can use **[String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** method with this Regex  `/^http/`, and this is the function you will need :

```
$('span.value').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().match(/^http/)) {
        $(this).addClass('url');
        console.log("OK");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('notURL');
        console.log("not OK");
    }
});
```

This is your **[updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/rkws8bs6/24/)**.

Answer (score -1):

The function `$('span.value').text()`, like all jQuery getters, only returns the value of the first element in the collection. Use [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to access each of the elements' `text()`, one by one.

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('span.value').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().indexOf('http') == 0 ) 
        {
            $(this).addClass('url'); 
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('notURL');
        }
    })
});
```